# Angular JS: Summation of columns at end of table using two dates and also search box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am newbie to Angualr js. Main two goals:
1.Between the date filter,Summation of Nobot and Total Downtime should be calculated.

```
Start Date :2016-08-02    End Date:2016-08-06
    J_Id     M_Date         Total Downtime   Nobot
    A        2016-08-01        230            230
    B        2016-08-02        150            540
                               380            770
```

2.According to J_Id, Same as above should be calculated.
For eg:

```
Search Box:  C
J_Id     M_Date         Total Downtime   Nobot
C        2016-08-22        250            250
C        2016-07-01        150            150
                           400            400
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="search"/>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Total Downtime</th>
<th>Total Runtime</th>
<th>Issued Bottles </th>
<th>Actual Production</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="user in result| filtered: startDate: endDate | filter:search"> 
                            <td>{{user.J_Id}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.M_Date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.Tot_D | filter:{"J_Id":search}}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.NoBot}}</td>

                    </tr>

<tr>

                        <td>{{result| sumOfValue:'J_Id'}}</td>
                        <td>{{result| sumOfValue:'M_Date'}}</td>
                        <td>{{result | sumOfValue:'Tot_D'}}</td>
                        <td>{{result | sumOfValue:'NoBot'}}</td>

                        </tr> 
</table>

Angular JS:
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);



  app.filter('sumOfValue', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        debugger;
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            sum = sum + parseInt(v[key]);
        });        
        return sum;
    }
}); 

app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,$http){
 $scope.startDate = "2016-05-08";
    $scope.endDate = "2016-05-09";

    $scope.result = [
       {
            "J_Id":'A'
            "M_Date" : "2016-08-01",
            "Tot_D" : 230,
            "Nobot":150

        },{
             "J_Id":'B'
             "M_Date" : "2016-08-02",
            "Tot_D" : 230,
            "Nobot":540
        },{
           "J_Id":'A'
           "M_Date" : "2016-08-03",
            "Tot_D" : 240,
            "Nobot":160
        },{
        "J_Id":'A'
            "M_Date" : "2016-09-01",
            "Tot_D" : 750,
            "Nobot":250
        },{
        "J_Id":'B'
             "M_Date" : "2016-09-02",
            "Tot_D" : 250,
            "Nobot":150
        },{
        "J_Id":'C'
            "M_Date" : "2016-08-22",
            "Tot_D" : 250,
            "Nobot":150
        },{
         "J_Id":'C'
           "M_Date" : "2016-07-01",
            "Tot_D" : 250,
            "Nobot":150
        },{
        "J_Id":'B'
            "M_Date" : "2016-10-01",
            "Tot_D" : 250,
            "Nobot":150
        }
    ]
});
app.filter("filtered", function($filter) {
    return function(items, from, to) {
     return $filter('filter')(items, "M_Date", function(v) {
      var date = moment(v);
      return date >= moment(from) && date <= moment(to);
     } );
    };
   }); 


</script>
```

I had written the code for Date filter and Summation, but I am little bit confusion in ng-repeat.Please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The case is wrong on NoBot, it should match what is in the script Nobot.  If you try to use inline filters in the ng-repeat you will also have to filter the data you are filtering with sumOfValue.  I would suggest adding a button to the filter and call a function to filter in the controller and then the sumOfValue can use the newly filtered array.

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="filterData()">filter</button>
```

and the function

```
$scope.filterData = function() {
 $scope.filteredResult = angular.copy($scope.result);
 $scope.filteredResult = $filter('filter')($scope.filteredResult, $scope.search);
 $scope.filteredResult = $filter('filtered')($scope.filteredResult, $scope.startDate, $scope.endDate);
};
```

here is a link to a working example.  http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/gMaqzE

The dates are hard coded in the controller so I always call the filter function with the controller loads to initially filter by the dates.